# Python:Data Frame object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to create a function that takes a filename as input and just read it using pandas. However, as i run the program it throws the error.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import re

product_description=[]
category=[]

    def get_data(filename):
        with open(filename,'r') as excelfile:
            excelfilereader=pd.read_excel(filename)
            next(excelfilereader)
            for rows in excelfilereader:
                product_description.append(str[rows][0])
                category_description.append(str[rows][1])
            return print(product_description)




get_data('D:\\android\\data1.xlsx')
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-db04dbb9b801> in <module>()
     16         return print(product_description)
     17 
---> 18 get_data('D:\\android\\data1.xlsx')
     19 

<ipython-input-5-db04dbb9b801> in get_data(filename)
     10     with open(filename,'r') as excelfile:
     11         excelfilereader=pd.read_excel(filename)
---> 12         next(excelfilereader)
     13         for rows in excelfilereader:
     14             product_description.append(str[rows][0])

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not an iterator
```

Comment: Yes, it is not. What did you expect `next(excelfilereader)` to do? `pd.read_excel` returns a fully materialized pandas dataframe. Why did you expect `next` to work on a dataframe? And for that matter, what do you think iterating over a data-frame does?

Comment: i did tried it with csv file reader on the csv file it worked there so how can i change my code to work on the excel file.

Comment: why did you use `print`  with `return`statement

Comment: `csv` is a totally different module from `pandas`. I suggest if you want to learn to use pandas, you take a look at the pandas [tutorial](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html)

Comment: Moreover What's `str` here,

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can do like this instead of many codes, 
`df=pd.read_excel(filename)
product_description=df[col1].values.tolist()
category=df[col2].values.tolist()`

Comment: **Read the docs, always** : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html - The solution is as easy as `pd.read_excel(open('my_file.xlsx', 'r'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you don't need to use `with open(filename,'r') as excelfile:`.
   pandas can read excel file directily.
2. if you intend second sheet of excel file with
       `next(excelfilereader)`. you can select sheet by option `sheet_name`
       like this `excelfilereader=pd.read_excel(filename , sheet_name=0 ,
       index_col=None)`
3. In your code, you append content from first row, so you need to set
   `header = None`

So full code for this function like below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import re

raw_xlsx_path='test.xlsx'


filename = raw_xlsx_path
product_description=[]
category=[]

def get_data(filename):
    excelfilereader=pd.read_excel(filename , sheet_name=0 , index_col=None , header=None)
    product_description = excelfilereader.iloc[:,0].values.tolist()
    category_description = excelfilereader.iloc[:,1].values.tolist()
    return print(product_description)


get_data(filename)
```

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `.values` for explicit type casting. it's ok to skip that.